# Phaser 3: Detect x y coordinate when overlapping

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework, overlap

I am trying to detect the x y coordinate overlapping of a canvas texture (a land) when there is an object (a bullet) hitting it. I can find the position of the object by using: object.x and object.y, but the position is not the overlapping position of the canvas texture.
Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Interesting question, but can you share some code and/or some more context? since your question throughs up many questions: are you using physics or not? if so which engine arcade, matter, ... ?  will there be only one overlapping coordinate, I assume, if the bullet is bigger than 1px there should be serveral, or? If so which one should be returned, or should a list of overlapping points be returned?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, *if you are using arcade physics*, is discussed here: https://phaser.discourse.group/t/pixelperfect-collision-or-hittest-between-object-and-any-coordinate-not-pointer/6377

With a working demo here: https://codepen.io/samme/pen/JjYYqaZ

**The gist is:** use the physics `overlap` function ([documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.54.0/focus/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Factory-overlap)), and in the `processCallback` function *(the function that, says if the overlap should trigger)*, check if the pixel of the "logo" (in your case the land), is visible or not `this.textures.getPixelAlpha(x, y , "logo") === 255` ([documenation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.54.0/focus/Phaser.Textures.TextureManager-getPixelAlpha)).

Depending how you want the bullet to overlap, you would have to tweak the position *(x, y)* calculation for the `getPixelAlpha` function. In the above mentioned example the center of the ball/bullet is used to detect the overlap.

```js
  this.physics.add.overlap(
      bullet,
      land,
      function overlapCallback(bullet, land) {
          ...
      },
      function processCallback(bullet, land) {
         let x = Math.floor(ball.body.center.x - landTopLeft.x);
         let y = Math.floor(ball.body.center.y - landTopLeft.y); 
         return this.textures.getPixelAlpha(x, y, "land") === 255;
     });
```

Comment: Thanks, winner_joiner, this is what I want, but there is trouble when I use the getTopLeft() function. I call: 
`this.textures1 = this.textures.get('canvastextures')`
and then call: 
`this.x = Math.floor(overlap2.x-this.textures1.getTopLeft().x)`
The result: this.textures1.getTopLeft() is not a function

Comment: @CSNo.1 you have to call the `getTopLeft()` on the gameobject, that was added to the scene [link docu](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Components.GetBounds.html#getTopLeft__anchor ), not the `texture`, since the texture doesn't have this function, or a position on the scene. I hope this information helps you.

Comment: @CSNo.1 If you check out the line 13 and 15 in the codepen-example you should see what I mean.